# Is there a backward equivalent to w?

Tags: navigation

- You can go forward, to the beginning of next word, with `w`/`W`.
- You can go forward, to the end of the word, with `e`/`E`
- You can go backward, to the beginning of the word whit `b`/`B`
- How do you go backward, to the end of the previous word ?

... except for:

```
:map <F1> bbe
:map <S-F1> BBE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a duplicate of this, but the commands are `ge` and `gE`.